# How to simplify Javascript If/Then Multiples?

Tags: javascript, slider, nivo-slider

I am not a programming pro. I am trying to give the user a choice of activating different slideshows, and for that, I need to activate the one selected, and deactivate the others. Now, I have four slideshows; but I could have 20 too. And for the 20, this bit of code would really look ugly:

```
        function setSlider(val)
        {
            if (val == 1)
            {
                $('#slider1').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            if (val == 2)
            {
                $('#slider2').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            if (val == 3)
            {
                $('#slider3').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById('slider4').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
            if (val == 4)
            {
                $('#slider4').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider4').style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
```

I am pretty sure there is something nicer to achieve. Something like

```
        function setSlider(val)
        {
                $('#slider' . val).nivoSlider();
                //loop here from 1 to 20
                document.getElementById('slider' . val).style.visibility = 'hidden';
                // loop end
                document.getElementById('slider' . val).style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
```

I tried it out, but it doesn't work... Could anyone give me a hint what I could do? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems like a common case of _iditis_... Use classes instead of incremental ids everything will be easier. Then you can target elements by index within a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something like […]

Yeah, you've got it. Only the string concatenation operator in JavaScript is the plus, not the dot. For the loop, use a simple for-statement:

```
function setSlider(val) {
     $('#slider' + val).nivoSlider();
     for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
          document.getElementById('slider' + i).style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
     document.getElementById('slider' + val).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Comment: Looks like the most elegant solution. And works (almost 100%). Trying to tweak it a bit. Thanks so much for everybody's help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below syntax :-

```
function setSlider(val)
    {
            $("#slider").hide(); 
            $("#slider"+val).nivoSlider();
            //loop here from 1 to 20
            for(var i = 1;i<=20;i++){
              $("#slider"+i).hide();
            }
            // loop end
            $("#slider"+val).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can consider the switch/case statement

```
 function setSlider(val)
        {
                document.getElementById('slider').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                document.getElementById('slider4').style.visibility = 'hidden';

switch(val){
case 1:
                $('#slider1').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider1').style.visibility = 'visible';
       break;

case2:          $('#slider2').nivoSlider();
                document.getElementById('slider2').style.visibility = 'visible';
       break;
etc,.
```

this will help in simplifying.

you can also consider to hide all elements before the case statement and show elements based on the case, this will reduce your code further and simplify it more.

you can also use `$('#slider"+val).show();`

```
 function setSlider(val)
            {
                    $('#slider').hide();
                    $('#slider1').hide();
                    $('#slider2').hide();
                    $('#slider3').hide();
                    $('#slider4').hide();
                    $('#slider'+val).show();
}
```